# systemd timer: enable service for specific time ranges only

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

Say I want a a program to be active between 12:00h and 13:00h on a desktop machine (i.e. if PC is on at either time cannot be guaranteed). I'll assume I can use systemd units for this.

Starting service `A` with a timer and accounting for poweroff times is simple:

*A.timer*

```
[Timer]
Unit=A
OnCalendar=*-*-* 12:00:00
Persistent=true
```

Stopping `A` could be done with a conflicting service as [suggested earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265704/start-stop-a-systemd-service-at-specific-times)

*A.service* (with conflict):

```
#add conflict to A.service
[Unit]
Description=This is A.service
Conflicts=killA.service
#make sure killA considers A to be active
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

*killA.service*:

```
 [Unit]
 Description=kills A
 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
 ExecStart=/bin/true
 #kill only if A is running:
 Requires=A.service
```

*killA.timer*

```
[Timer]
Unit=killA
OnCalendar=*-*-* 13:00:00
Persistent=true
```

Now there are several possible scenarios:

- Powered on from 11h-14h: start and stop as expected
- Powered on from 11h to 12:30h: start as expected but never stopped -> what will happen at next poweron?

  - at 12:45: will A start? (last start less than 24h ago)
  - at 14h: killA should not run as A should not be active
  - at 12:15 next day? (last start less than 24 h ago, but killA start was missed)
  - at 12:45 next day? (last start >24h ago, but killA <24h ago. Will it be stopped by killA?)
- Powered on from 12:30 to 14h: start and stop as expected (due to persistence in A.timer)
- powered on at 14h: A starts due to persistence. Will killA deactivate it immediately due to dependency? Can starting A be avoided in the first place?

In short:

**How to use systemd timers to make sure a service is active in a given time interval and inactive outside the time interval independently of shutdowns/boots ?**

---

Hands-on use-case example: allow `ssh`-access only at working hours.

PS: Maybe I just don't get systemd timers very well, yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirements.

I can confirm that two timers catching up at boot result in a race condition, with a random outcome.

And what about a scenario where the system reboots *more than once* between 12 and 13. `Persistent` may not be of any help in that case.

My conclusion (but I would love to be proven wrong) is that systemd is simply not made for this use case.

My work around is to use the above configuration, without the `Persistent` flags. Then I create a new `idle` service dedicated to handle state after startup. This service compares the current time with the current target service state, and starts/stops the service if they do not match. Note that the start/stop times need to be duplicated in the timers and in the 'startup manager' service script, which is not ideal.

That's the only reliable way I found to ensure my service is running during the selected time period, regardless of the various reboots.

Comment: The `idle`-service is starting a shell script, then? In pseudo-code `if [ <time in active interval> && <service inactive> ] ; then <start service> ; elif [ <time in incative interval> && <service active> ] ; then <stop service> ; fi` or do you manage this by `systemd`-logics?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.