# Pause or stop systemd service while another is running

Tags: systemd

Regarding **systemd**, is it possible to pause or stop a running service (ensuring all data have been written) while another service is running?

My scenario looks like this: I have built a sensor (based upon a Raspberry Pi Zero W and running Kali Linux). The daemon process for sensing is starting (as systemd service unit `sensor.service`) right after the boot process finishes.

```
[Unit]
Description=Arbitrary sensor
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/sense --daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The sensor is collecting and storing the data locally and continuously. The data is being computed periodically and its result shall be sent away (over the network). *Now, for the time of computation **the sensor shall stop receiving further data to ensure all data have been written**, before the computation starts.* Right after the computation is done, the sensor shall start to collect further data.

Yes, I could write a script by myself which handles that:

```bsh
systemctl stop sensor.service
systemctl start compute.service  # Terminates itself
systemctl start sensor.service
```

But I wonder, whether this is a scenario that can be handled by systemd for me? Especially without the need to write a script by myself. What I'm imaging is a `compute.timer` unit which handles the three lines above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script you wrote in your question has a small problem. It doesn't wait for `compute.service` to stop before starting `sensor.service`.

---

## Strategies

Here are four strategies.  I think the third one is my favorite.

### Find another means of concurrency

I'm not sure that stopping `sensor.service` is necessary.  It sounds like the reason you would do this is so that new data doesn't affect the computation.  In that case, I'd take a snapshot of the data file.  Then compute off of that snapshot.  That snapshot won't update during the compute process, solving your concurrency problem.  Using `PrivateTmp=` means that your `/tmp` is actually a fresh temporary mount which is deleted when the service stops.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/compute.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/cp /var/lib/sensor/data /tmp/data_to_compute
ExecStart=/usr/bin/compute /tmp/data_to_compute
PrivateTmp=yes
```

### Do it all in a timed script

If it really is necessary to stop sensor.service, your script idea isn't bad.  I'd probably make `compute.timer` which calls `compute.service` which contains `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/compute.sh`.  That would contain something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
systemctl stop sensor.service
/usr/bin/compute /var/lib/sensor/data
systemctl start sensor.service
```

### Use systemd relationships

In the previous example, we called `systemctl` from inside a script run by systemd.  Something about that just doesn't feel right.  The `Conflicts=` relationship in systemd means that when the service is started, it will automatically stop the conflicting service.  systemd doesn't have a relationship to start a process when another finishes, so we can use `ExecStartPost=` for that here:

Therefore adding this to `compute.service`:

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=sensor.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/compute /var/lib/sensor/data
ExecStopPost=systemctl start sensor.service
```

will achieve your goal of stopping `sensor.service` whenever `compute.timer` triggers.  Instead of a custom shell script, we have moved everything into the unit file.  The discomfort of using `systemctl` from inside of systemd isn't solved, but at least we've reduced it and made it more transparent (instead of hiding it in a script).

### Two timers

This is a little in-elegant, but if you want to replace the `ExecStopPost=` line, you could have two timers.  `compute.timer` is set to compute as frequently as you like (just like you are already doing).  If you want to compute 5 minutes worth of data, then set `sensor.timer` to launch `sensor.service` 5 minutes earlier than you trigger `compute.timer`.

---

## Putting it all togeather

Regardless of the strategy, you'll need `compute.timer` and `compute.service`, but shouldn't need to touch `sensor.service`.  I realized that you might have been asking how to make a systemd timer.  Here is how I would completely implement strategy 3:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/compute.timer
[Unit]
Description=Timer to trigger computations every 15 minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/15

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

`compute.timer` (above) will start `compute.service` (below) every 15 minutes.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/compute.service
[Unit]
Description=Runs computation (triggered by compute.timer)
Conflicts=sensor.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/compute /var/lib/sensor/data
ExecStopPost=systemctl start sensor.service
```

Then just enable the timer (and start if you don't want to reboot):

```
systemctl enable compute.timer
systemctl start compute.timer
```

Comment: This is really a very good compendium of possible solutions to my problem. Also my favorite is the 3rd one. Thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

The best practices to face my problem I found so far, are described in another question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318744/208465